# presentViewController didnt work appdelegate

Tags: ios, iphone

line `presentViewController` crash app

```
@interface VVPassbook : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

-(void)gotPassbookFromUrl:(NSURL *)passbookUrl;

@end

#import "VVPassbook.h"

@implementation VVPassbook

    -(void)gotPassbookFromUrl:(NSURL *)passbookUrl
{
        //present view controller to add the pass to the library
                PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
                [vc setDelegate:(id)self.delegate];
                [self.delegate presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
    @end
```

im call this method in AppDelegate.m in method

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
    (NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
VVPassbook *pass = [[VVPassbook alloc] init];
pass.delegate = self.window.rootViewController;
[pass gotPassbookFromUrl:MYURL ];
}
```

all times error

```
reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <VVRightManuViewController: 0x15dd28460>.'
```

Comment: You need to simply call it on your view controller and not on it's delegate.. [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Your question is not clear what is "self.delegate" here  ?? clear your question plz.

Answer (score 0):

you should present a viewController from a UIViewController, i.e., self
(if self is a viewcontroller).

Note that you will get a "Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy"-warning when self (this viewcontroller) is detached from the Main Window.

Solution: always use addChildViewController: to child viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `self.delegate` to `push` the `view Controller`,
simple write

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in the place of

```
 [self.delegate presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```